# Reading class attribute from tr tag

Tags: c#, attributes

I have an HTML document with many `<tr>` tags in it. There is one specific table that I want to go through and make an array of id tags within each `<tr>`. Each of the `<tr>`'s have the same class value. For example:

```
...
<table>
<tr class="blah" id="234">...</tr>
<tr class="blah" id="435">...</tr>
...</table>
```

Within the HTMLDocument, I made an HTMLElementCollection using:

```
document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
```

I would think the logical thing to do from there is to go through each row and use something along the lines of

```
row.GetAttribute("class")
```

or

```
row.GetAttribute("id")
```

however both of those return a blank string. I can see that the `outterHTML` attribute of the elements says "`<tr class="blahblah" id="435345"><td>...`

Any suggestions other than having to dissect the string of the `outterHTML` attribute?

Comment: After double checking the output, I realized that the HTML page contains 28 hits for the tr tag, but my collection from GetElementsByTagName only shows 11 items. It looks like the bigger problem may be that not all tr tags are picked up. I don't know if that helps in solving this problem at all...

Comment: Can you add your implementation so far? This should include the definition of `document` and `row`.

Comment: How are you processing this document? WebBrowser control?

Comment: I have a WebBrowser in the form. Here is the implementation code:
HtmlDocument htmlPage = wbGoogle.Document; //the WebBrowser control
HtmlElementCollection htmlTableRows = htmlPage.GetElementsByTagName("tr");

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was. When running `row.GetAttribute()`, I had the wrong property in there. While the HTML looked like this:

```
<tr class="blah">
```

The C# code should look like this:

```
row.GetAttribute("className");
```

And it turns out that the reason only half of the `<tr>` tags showed up was because the page does a full load unpopulated, then refreshes itself fully populated with the rest of the `<tr>` tags in place.